# How to diff dates in typescript?

Tags: typescript

My function

```
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number | null> => {
  if (date === "") return null;
  const now: Date = new Date(date);
  const start: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff =
    now - // ERROR
    start + // ERROR
    (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  if (!day) return null;
  return Number(day);
};
```

The error I get is

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are not applicable on `Date` type, which is what your `now` and `start` are, and that's why the error. It seems like you want the difference between the dates in milliseconds, so do this instead:

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/9WvPrN)

```ts
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number | null> => {
  if (date === "") return null;
  const now: Date = new Date(date);
  const start: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff =
    now.getTime() - 
    start.getTime() + 
    (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  if (!day) return null;
  return Number(day);
};
```

Another hack is to use unary `+` before the `Date` values `now` and `start` which converts the `Date` into milliseconds. Here is how:

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/4WyBKw)

```ts
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number | null> => {
  if (date === "") return null;
  const now: Date = new Date(date);
  const start: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff =
    +now - 
    +start + 
    (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  if (!day) return null;
  return Number(day);
};
```